# How to send data another page and list with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I just started learning Kotlin. I am making an application that saves bank (IBAN) information. I save the information locally using sharedpreferences.

I save the information to the list and save it as sharedpreferences.

Information is recorded on page 2 and I want to list this recorded information on page 1.

I was doing this simply in Flutter, but I couldn't understand how to do it in Kotlin.

[image]
[image]

```
package com.example.ibansfer

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.ibansfer.databinding.ActivityAddIbanBinding
import com.example.ibansfer.models.IbanModel
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken


class AddIbanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddIbanBinding
    private var ibanList: ArrayList<IbanModel> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAddIbanBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setTitle("IBAN bilgisi ekle")
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        val sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("ibans", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        fun saveData() {
            val gson = Gson()
            val json = gson.toJson(ibanList)
            editor.putString("ibans", json)
            editor.apply()
        }

        binding.ibanSaveBttn.setOnClickListener {
            val ibanOwner = binding.ibanOwner.text.toString()
            val bankName = binding.bankName.text.toString()
            val ibanAdress = binding.ibanAdress.text.toString()

            if (ibanOwner.isEmpty() || bankName.isEmpty() || ibanAdress.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Lütfen tüm alanları doldurunuz.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                ibanList.add(IbanModel(ibanOwner, bankName, ibanAdress))
                saveData()
                Toast.makeText(this, "IBAN bilgileri başarıyla eklendi.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()


            }


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: If you want to transmit data between different activities, you need to use intents.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the data in SharedPrefferences, you can always retrieve it back in the other screen.

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences("ibans", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
val myString = sharedPref.getString("ibans", defaultValue)
```

You can even set up a SharedPrefferences listener that will get notified whenever new data is added to it and act accordingly.

```
val sharedPreferencesListener =
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { sharedPreferences, key -> 
// code to execute on changes here 
}
activity?.getPreferences("ibans", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      ?.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferencesListener )
```

Also don't forget to unregister using `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

Or alternatively, use Intents as the comment suggests to pass data between Activities/Fragments.

Comment: i want to list all req data. does it happen this way

Comment: @sb389ydubw yes, the listener triggers on any change, but then you can retrieve all the data stored inside it. with, or without a listener set up.